# C# application how could i implement dictionary or hashtable for this?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

This is my problem, i want to write a basic console application where i enter a date as input, if that date hasnt been entered the application then allow a time to enter a note, i.e for 07/08/2013  for time 5:00 - 7:00 pm enter text blah blah

then application will keep looping, if i enter the same date, i shouldnt be able to enter 
the same times as above, but i should be able to enter 7:00 to 8 for example.

i was thinking of using dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, Booking> BookingDict = new Dictionary<string, Booking>();
```

and adding date as id, but it seems only one element id can be entered uniquely

can some one please help

Comment: You can make key combination of Data-Time

Comment: Do you need to prevent overlaps? In your example, could I create an entry for 07/08/2013 from 6:00 PM - 8:00 PM ?

Comment: In your `string` example, what *exactly* are you using as the key(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a list or dictionary? If you will not be searching in it alot and do not have a lot of elements, you are probably best going with a generic list: `List<Booking>`

Then you can use LINQ to search through the list to retrieve the bookings that you need.

Comment: i dont have to use list or dictionery, but i don want to use linq thanks

Comment: Then use a 3 dimensional Dictionary have your key be the date and the object be another dictionary. The second dicitionary should have the time as the key. So to retrieve it would be 2 steps, first get the dictionary for the day, then retrieve the desired timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

create a key with two dateTime (the start and end dateTime). When you want to enter a new booking, check (with linq for instance) if there's a known end Datetime that is between your new start and end datetime and do the same with the known start datetime. If there is no overlap, add it.

Here's an example:

```
Dictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfo,object> test = new Dictionary<TwoUintsKeyInfo, object>();
        test.Add(new TwoUintsKeyInfo { IdOne = 3, IdTwo = 9 }, new object());
        test.Add(new TwoUintsKeyInfo { IdOne = 10, IdTwo = 15 }, new object());

        uint newStartPoint1 = 16,newEndPoint1=20;
        bool mayUse = (from result in test 
                            let newStartPointIsBetweenStartAndEnd = newStartPoint1.Between(result.Key.IdOne,result.Key.IdTwo)
                            let newEndPointIsBetweenStartAndEnd = newEndPoint1.Between(result.Key.IdOne,result.Key.IdTwo)
                            let completeOverlap = result.Key.IdOne < newStartPoint1 && result.Key.IdTwo > newEndPoint1
                            let oldDateWithingNewRange = result.Key.IdOne.Between(newStartPoint1, newEndPoint1) || result.Key.IdTwo.Between(newStartPoint1, newEndPoint1)
                            let FoundOne = 1
                            where newStartPointIsBetweenStartAndEnd || newEndPointIsBetweenStartAndEnd || completeOverlap || oldDateWithingNewRange
                            select FoundOne).Sum()==0;
```

using:

```
 public static class LinqExtentions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Note: For the compare parameters; First the low, than the High
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Bool</returns>
    public static bool Between<T1, T2, T3>(this T1 actual, T2 lowest, T3 highest)
        where T1 : IComparable
        where T2 : IConvertible
        where T3 : IConvertible
    {
        return actual.CompareTo(lowest.ToType(typeof(T1), null)) >= 0 &&
               actual.CompareTo(highest.ToType(typeof(T1), null)) <= 0;
    }
}

public class TwoUintsKeyInfo
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }

    public class EqualityComparerTwoUintsKeyInfo : IEqualityComparer<TwoUintsKeyInfo>
    {
        public bool Equals(TwoUintsKeyInfo x, TwoUintsKeyInfo y)
        {
            return x.IdOne == y.IdOne &&
                    x.IdTwo == y.IdTwo;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(TwoUintsKeyInfo x)
        {
            return (Math.Pow(x.IdOne, Math.E) + Math.Pow(x.IdTwo, Math.PI)).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it, seems to be working.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. As much as it looks like a great solution, its very complex, and i want to keep it simple. i want to use simple data structures like array/arraylist/list/linklist/dictionery and combination. Are you able to provide an example of how i could implement this without using LINQ, thanks

Comment: no ;-) But this is actually quit simple, isn't it. I wonder if there's someone with a even simpler solution...

Comment: by the way==>" i want to use simple data structures like array/arraylist/list/linklist/dictionery" did you notice I actually USE dictionaries? In this example I made sure you check for any overlap in time (in this case a uint, just as an example. You could also use datetime). If you want to check for any overlap, without linq, I think the code would be bigger and more complex if you want to check the same conditions as in this example. But feel free to alter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend a dictionary with the key being the date and the value be an array of 24 booleans represent hours. that is only if the booking is for full hours. if it's by the minute then the array will be too big and then another option might be needed.

each cell in the array is true if the hour is booked, for example if <07/08/13, booked[2] = true> means that hour 2-3 is booked on 07/08/13 is booked.

when you get a new booking you'll need to check each hour between the two. if you got hours 4-10 you'll need to check the value in 4,5,6,7,8,9. not the best efficiency i think, but not that bad if no one is booking a full week or so.

sum it up my answer is using

```
Dictionary<string/DateTime, bool[24]> bookingTbl
```

Comment: that looks good, can you provide an example please? or extract